# Jquery variable output

Tags: jquery

My problem is driving me nuts.

I have declared som variables like this

```
var tip01 = "This is my first tip";
var tip02 = "This is my second tip";
```

Depending on the value in my querystring I want to write out my tips.

my querystring: ex ?myQSvalue=01

```
var myQSvalue = getQueryString('myQSvalue');
var myTip = 'tip' + myQSvalue;

 $("#output").html(myTip);
```

But the output is: `tip01` insted of `This is my first tip`.

How can I achieve this and output the content in my declared varable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

rather than different variabes, you should be using an array

```
var myTips = [];
myTips[0] = "This is my first tip";
myTips[1] = "This is my second tip";
```

Then pass an index on the querystring `?myQSvalue=0`

And read from the array:

```
var myQSvalue = parseInt(getQueryString('myQSvalue'),10);
$("#output").html(myTips[myQSvalue]);
```

Comment: Thank you, i went with the array approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest defining the tips in an array instead, but you should be able to use:

```
$("#output").html(window[myTip]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach has already been pointed out by Jamiec, but just for future reference, you can refer to global variables as properties of the global context:

```
var myQSvalue = getQueryString('myQSvalue');
var myTip = 'tip' + myQSvalue;

 $("#output").html(window[myTip]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. I went with the array approach and it works great.

But the $("#output").html(window[myTip]); didn´t work for me.

In some cases that approach would be handy.